# Merging the Data of 2 Tables such that a definite sequence is followed

Tags: mysql, union

I have 2 MySQL Tables

firstTable

```
 |Name   |    Value |
----------------------------
 |Martin |    Yes   |
 |Joseph |    Yes   |
 |Joseph |    Yes   |
 |Jack   |    No    |
```

secondTable

```
 |Name           |    Value |
---------------------------------------
 |Joseph Desouza |    Yes   |
 |Joseph Desouza |    Yes   |
```

The specification of "firstTable" is it contains all types of record
The specification of "secondTable" is it contains only records of "Joseph Dezouza"

Now, how can I get the final result array through MySql query such that, I get the merged result as below, such that the list of Joseph should appear first and then should start the list of Joseph Desouza

```
 |Name           |    Value |
 ----------------------------
 |Martin         |    Yes   |
 |Joseph         |    Yes   |
 |Joseph         |    Yes   |
 |Joseph Desouza |    Yes   |
 |Joseph Desouza |    Yes   |
 |Jack           |    No    |
```

The only thing which i understand is that I can get this using Union but cannot figure out how to get the sequence right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM firstTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM secondTable) a
ORDER BY Name DESC;
```

Which gives this order:

```
Name           value
-------------------
Martin          Yes
Joseph Desouza  Yes
Joseph Desouza  Yes
Joseph          Yes
Joseph          Yes
Jack            No
```

Or you can specify the wanted order (in this case you should already know the values!!)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM firstTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM secondTable) a
ORDER BY FIELD(Name, "Martin", "Joseph", "Joseph Desouza", "Jack");
```

Which will give:

```
Name           value
-------------------
Martin          Yes
Joseph          Yes
Joseph          Yes
Joseph Desouza  Yes
Joseph Desouza  Yes
Jack            No
```

If some values arent included in `FIELD`, they will be listed first in ASC order by default !!

Comment: also check the difference between "UNION ALL" and "UNION DISTINCT"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

both tables should have the same fieldds:

```
(SELECT * FROM firstTable
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM secondTable)
    ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Comment: Bang on Solution... If Enissay would not have answered I was about to accept yours as an answer... But he was more informative with possibilities and scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

By using UNION we cannot display all the values because UNION will not allow duplicate values. So use UNION ALL to get all data